# Chrome extension: display an overlay dropdown menu with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to chrome extension developement. I try to display as an overlay a dropdown menu using bootstrap, when a user select a text on a given web page. I want the dropdown menu to be very close to the selection so I can suggest some actions to the user.
here is my code in `content.js`:

```
window.onload = function () {
// Add the menu to the top of the page.
var dropdownMenuDOM = document.createElement("div");
dropdownMenuDOM.setAttribute("class", "show-dropdownmenu");
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(dropdownMenuDOM);

// Lets listen to mouseup DOM events.

document.addEventListener(
   "mouseup",
   function (e) {
     var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
     console.log("selected >" + selection);
     if (selection.length > 0) {
         renderDropdownMenu(e.clientX, e.clientY, selection);
     }
  },
  false
 );
 // Move that bubble to the appropriate location.
 function renderDropdownMenu(mouseX, mouseY, selection) {
    dropdownMenuDOM.innerHTML = selection;
    dropdownMenuDOM.style.top = mouseX + "px";
    dropdownMenuDOM.style.left = mouseY + "px";
    dropdownMenuDOM.style.visibility = "visible";
  }
};
```

in addition to this, I'm injecting some style like this:

```
.show-dropdownmenu {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: -webkit-gradient(
       linear,
       left top,
       left bottom,
       from(#2e88c4),
       to(#075698)
    );
 }
```

The result I try to acheive is to have something similar to what Altasian Confluence pages do:

[image]

So far, I'm not displaying a dropdown menu, juste some kind of bubble. I'm using element coordinate for that but it's not working very well, as the selected text is displayed on top of the page where ever I click.

Comment: Are you injecting any styles into the page? If so, have you've defined any styles for the `show-dropdownmenu` class ?

Comment: thanks @Titus for the comment, you're right, I'm injecting some css -> see update question

Comment: `clientX/Y` doesn't take into account scrolling, you can try to use `pageX/Y` but I doubt that will fix it because the page that you inject this in may have some styling for `div` elements or even for the `body` element which will interfere with the element that you're creating.

Comment: You should look into [shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_shadow_DOM) it is a way of isolating your elements styling.

Comment: @Titus PageX/Y gives a better result. Now I'm strugling with the dropdown menu as it doesn't import bootstrap... anyways I can make bootstrap work? or any other css dropdown menu that I can use? I found some ont the internet that doesn't work

Comment: To use clientX/clientY you need `position:fixed`. If you want `absolute` then use pageX/pageY.